# Need to automate crunching of excel data?

Tags: c#, excel, automation

I have processes running on Windows XP/7. They generate weekly .csv data files. I have a bunch of excel formulas that crunch the numbers for each .csv file produced for the week separately and then when adding the weekly data to the one big spreadsheet containing all the data put together.

The number of rows varies each week and for each process. So I can't hardcode that number in my dozens of formulas. So right now I go through this stupid process of manually entering the formulas each week into the .csv files.

There's got to be a way of automating this. Just now I quickly looked into doing this through C# or VB code. Could somebody recommend the best way to do this. Is C# or VB the right way to go? If so, any hints on how to put it all together - what's the model to use? For example, would it look something like this:

- C# module reads in .csv data file
- C# module creates an Excel spreadsheet and populates it with the .csv data
- C# module runs my formulas on the all the rows.

Is that how one would approach it? Is there a better way for somebody who has very limited knowledge of C# or VB? I know Java and C++.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need Excel at all to perform the calculations ? Is it only to avoid having to it all in code ?

Comment: Well Excel is the ideal tool not just for the formulas but also for graphing, visualizing, sorting, filtering, etc the data.

Comment: I agree, for the end result Excel is a great presentation tool. But do calculations have to be done in it ? Isn't this what you're trying to avoid ?

Comment: Well for right now the calculations are relatively basic arithmetic so you might be right if I didn't have an idea that in the future i might need to run complex statistical analysis for which there are ready formulas in Excel.

Comment: So I was thinking that it would be a nice solution using something like C# which interoperates with Excel through Excel libs for C#.

Comment: Ok. So, are the formulas always the same for each "process", independent of the number of rows ?

Answer (score 1):

From your explanations in comments, it appears that having a series of template Excel sheets would greatly facilitate the task.

So, for each process that generates data, you say the formulas are always the same, meaning that the columns are always the same (am I right?).

So, even if you don't know how many rows of data, you can still either create a template where only the first row is filled with formulas, and then you simply copy that row over and over, filling it with data as needed, or, you could fill a relatively "comfortable" number of rows with those same formulas, and fill in the data.

There are tons of atricles on how to Interop with Excel, so it's beyond  my intent to provide you with specific code, but the idea is good.

If I can allow myself, I have worked in the past with a very interesting tool call [Flexcel Studio for .NET](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp), and I have found it to be of great help when it came to generating Excel sheets based on such templates.

Cheers

Comment: No not looking for code. Just what the options are. It sounds like this is a nice alternative to what I was thinking or at least it is worth exploring. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, I would recommend performing the calculations outside of excel if possible. There are plenty of stats libraries out there that are friendlier to work with than going through the hassle of moving data into excel, applying formulas to cell ranges, and so on.

If you **really** want to go the excel route, you can either use open-source libraries such as [EPPLUS](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (.NET) or [POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) (Java) to work with .XLSX files directly. Some libraries do not support [function evaluation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) so you will need to consider this when deciding on a library to use.

If you go with [COM interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), you should read about about the following: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

As for the C# or VB (if not java with POI), I would go with C#.   C# syntax is similar to java.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a really simple solution to this problem.

Add 1 piece of auxiliary data to the .csv file either programmatically when running my process or when creating the .xlsx file (with all the formulas) from the .csv file. The auxiliary piece of data is the row count which will be in some known location.

Then modify all my formulas to use the INDIRECT function to specify the range using the cell
with the auxiliary piece of data.

I think that might work.